# Proper function prefix notation

Tags: function

Not sure if this is the right place to post this question but:

If I have a list of functions that I am listing in a spec doc, lets say

```
MyObj_Func1
MyObj_Func2
MyObj_Func3
```

and so on but I just want to list the core name of the functions (`Func1`, `Func2`, `Func3`) How do I note at the top to say "the functions listed below all start with `"MyObj_"`?

Something like: `MyObj_::` and then `...` before the function names in the list?

Comment: programmers.stackexchange.com could be better place. Specifying language you are trying to write documentation for maybe useful. (Personal opinion - prefixes are bad for your health :) )

Comment: hahah fair enough, its just for a test document where Im listing all of the functions from one object being tested. Its in C, but realistically the prog language shouldnt matter

Comment: I see. Language matters as each have unique way of naming class members (and for C prefix is one of traditional ways - so as long as actual names of functions match your documentation you are ok). I.e. for Java/C# writing `MyClass::MyMethod` would be confusing, when for C++ both `MyClass::MyMethod` and `MyClass.MyMethod` may work ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would leave the prefixes in the documentation. Though repetitive, it's what I would expect to see (as a c developer).

For example see the GNOME docs for hash table (which I consider to be fairly well done): https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.31/glib-Hash-Tables.html.